# Example on how to send SQL from dos command line with T4eSQL (free)?

Tags: command-line

I found this free command line tool:
T4eSQL from http://www.tools4ever.com/products/free/command/

I downloaded it but there's no example on how to use it for example with a ms access oracle database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
T4eSQL -d:"DSN=DataSourceName;UID=UsernameToDB;PW=Password" -q:"my_query"
```

Put your SQL statement in the "my_query" part

Comment: Thanks didn't have time to try yet but will come back and say if it works when I will

Comment: Hi that works with odbc entry !

Answer (score 0):

With Version 3.52:

I have used this with good results.

```
t4esql -d:"DSN=DataSourcename;UID=DB_UserName;Pwd=DB_Password" -f:"Query or file name"
```

Note that the password parameter is `Pwd` vs `PW` and that the switch for the query statement or text file path is `-f:`

I used a user-based ODBC object to connect to our Server and DB.

I hope this helps as it seems I am rather late :)